# Why canvas image is drawn improperly when specific coordinates given

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to build Snake game in vanilla javascript. So far I have generated wall borders and defined coordinates where player initial head begins. But when I try it in the browser, a weird bug happens and I dont know why. Here is an example:

[image]

*1. A bug happens. Player head is that single dot on the field. Yet for some reason wall is also painted red (a player initial head color).*

Here is my javascript code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var xAxis = 600, yAxis = 600, wallImage, playerHeadImage;  // we defined that canvas is 600 x 600 big
var playerHeadInitialXpos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 28) + 1;  // We use 28 and 1, because 29 and 0 are occupied by walls in the worldTileSet
var playerHeadInitialYpos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 28) + 1;
console.log(playerHeadInitialXpos);
console.log(playerHeadInitialYpos);
var isGameOver = false;
var arrayLength = 30;
var worldTileSet = new Array(arrayLength);
var documentBody = document.body;


function wall(xPosition, yPosition) {
  this.name = 'Wall';
  this.xPosition = xPosition;
  this.yPosition = yPosition;
  isWall : true;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rect(this.xPosition, this.yPosition, 20, 20);  // since our keyboard is 30 * 30 squares (two dimensional array), then 600 / 30 = 20
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.drawImage(wallImage, this.xPosition, this.yPosition);
  ctx.restore();
}

function playerHead(xPosition, yPosition) {
  console.log("X body coordinate:" + xPosition + ", Y body coordinate: " + yPosition);
  this.name = 'Body';
  this.xPosition = xPosition;
  this.yPosition = yPosition;
  isPlayerBody : true;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rect(this.xPosition, this.yPosition, 20, 20);
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.drawImage(playerHeadImage, this.xPosition, this.yPosition);
  ctx.restore();
}

function processImages() {
  wallImage = new Image();
  playerHeadImage = new Image();
  wallImage.src = 'img/wall1.jpeg';
  playerHeadImage.src = 'img/red.jpg';
}

function setUpEnvironment() {

  if (wallImage.complete) {
    setUpNorthernGameBorder();
    setUpSouthernGameBorder();
    setUpEasternGameBorder();
    setUpWesternGameBorder();
    return;
  }

  setTimeout(function () {
    setUpEnvironment()
  }, 1000);
}

function setUpPlayer() {
  if (playerHeadImage.complete) {
    alert(1);
    setPlayerHeadInitialPosition();
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(function () {
    setUpPlayer()
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {  // <-- Here code begins
  processImages();
  initializeWorldTileSet();
  setUpEnvironment();
  setUpPlayer();
};

function setUpNorthernGameBorder() {
  var xPos = 0;
  for (var tile = 0; tile < arrayLength; tile++) {
    worldTileSet[tile][0] = new wall(xPos, yAxis - 600);
    xPos += 20;
  }
}

function setUpSouthernGameBorder() {
  var xPos = 0;
  for (var tile = 0; tile < arrayLength; tile++) {
    worldTileSet[tile][29] = new wall(xPos, yAxis - 20);
    xPos += 20;
  }
}

function setUpEasternGameBorder() {
  var yPos = 0;
  for (var tile = 0; tile < arrayLength; tile++) {
    worldTileSet[29][tile] = new wall(xAxis - 20, yPos);
    yPos += 20;
  }
}

function setUpWesternGameBorder() {
  var yPos = 0;
  for (var tile = 0; tile < arrayLength; tile++) {
    worldTileSet[0][tile] = new wall(xAxis - 600, yPos);
    yPos += 20;
  }
}

function initializeWorldTileSet() {  // Here we build two dimensional array which represents our game board
  for (var i = 0; i < worldTileSet.length; i++) {
    worldTileSet[i] = new Array(arrayLength);
  }
}

function setPlayerHeadInitialPosition() {  // <-- I suspect a bug happens here, but i dont know why
  var yPos = 0;
  console.log("playerHeadInitialXpos: " + playerHeadInitialXpos + ", playerHeadInitialYpos: " + playerHeadInitialYpos);
  worldTileSet[playerHeadInitialXpos][playerHeadInitialYpos] = new playerHead(playerHeadInitialXpos * 20, playerHeadInitialYpos * 20);

  worldTileSet[29][29] = new playerHead(580, 580);
  for (var tile = 0; tile < arrayLength; tile++) {
    yPos += 20;
    console.log("Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: " + 29 + ", Y: " + tile + ". Object: " + worldTileSet[29][tile] + ". Name: " + worldTileSet[29][tile].name);
  }
}
```

As you can see I have defined two objects and everything (except the grass) is an javascript object (walls, head). So I debugged a bit to see if those red colors on wall are player head objects and I got the following result:

```
Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 0. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 1. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 2. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 3. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 4. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 5. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 6. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 7. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 8. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 9. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 10. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 11. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 12. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 13. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 14. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 15. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 16. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 17. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 18. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 19. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 20. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 21. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 22. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 23. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 24. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 25. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 26. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 27. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 28. Object: [object Object]. Name: Wall
game.js:167 Eastern wall. Coordinates: X: 29, Y: 29. Object: [object Object]. Name: Body
```

*2. My debugging shows that even though some of the walls are red painted, they are still wall objects. Note: I purposly put the last red dot (head object) on the eastern border for debugging purposes.*

And here I dont have any idea, why it acts like that. I noticed that when the initial player head is more to the west, then this does not happen. It happens only when player head gets close enough to eastern wall. What could be the reason for such behaviour?

Attachments (image resources):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: does the "setPlayerHeadInitialPosition" function get called only once ?

Comment: @Stakvino yes it does

Comment: can you provide the 3 images used in your program (red, wall and grass) am trying to execute it on a browser. or maybe you have a jsfiddle/codepen link to your program ?

Comment: at first i think removing this line : worldTileSet[29][29] = new playerHead(580, 580); in "setPlayerHeadInitialPosition" function will remove the red square in the right bottom corner (it did for me).

Comment: yes it does. but that was just for debugging purposes. main problem is the other dots

Comment: i also added images for the game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are drawing the whole red square instead of taking only a 20x20 portion from it so you will have to replace :

```
ctx.drawImage(playerHeadImage, this.xPosition, this.yPosition);
```

with :

```
ctx.drawImage(playerHeadImage, this.xPosition, this.yPosition, 20, 20);
```

to take only 20x20 from the red square image. and i suggest personally because you only want to draw a red square to use fillrect instead of drawing an image like so :

```js
ctx.save();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(this.xPosition, this.yPosition, 20, 20);
ctx.clip();
ctx.restore();
```

instead of :

```js
ctx.save();
ctx.clip();
ctx.drawImage(playerHeadImage, this.xPosition, this.yPosition, 20, 20);
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) You saved the day!